# Covariance between squared bivariate geometrically distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, covariance, bivariate-distributions

If $X$ and $Y$ follows bivariate geometric distribution (where $EX=a$, $EY=b$, $Cov(X,Y)=c$ ) then how to obtain (determine) $Cov(X^2,Y)$?

Comment: How to obtain? By computation.

Comment: I don't think you have provided sufficient details to answer the question. The covariance you seek will also involve higher moments like $E[X^2]$, and product moments like $E[X^2 Y]$ which you have not provided. Moreover, the description 'bivariate Geometric distribution' is not sufficient to lock things down either, as there are arbitrarily many distributions that are bivariate Geometric, and you have not even defined which of the alternative Geometric marginals you are working with (e.g. $X = 0, 1, 2, \dots$ vs $X = 1, 2, 3,\dots$)

Comment: If I knew $E[X^2Y]$ I would determine $Cov(X^2,Y)$ easily. So, If you can help me about $E[X^2Y]$ it will solve my problem. And concerning bivariate geometric distribution... Let us say $P(X=x,Y=y)=\binom{x+y}{x}p^xq^y(1-p-q)$.

Answer (score 1):

The particular bivariate Geometric you provide in your comment above is the model provided by:

- Phatak and Sreehari (1981), Some characterizations of bivariate geometric distribution, *Journal of Indian Statistical Association*, 19, pp. 141-146.

... namely with joint pmf $f(x,y)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/bivariategeometricdistpmf.png))</sub>

Then, $Cov(X,Y)$ is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/covariancebivariategeometricpmf.png))</sub>

and $Cov(X^2,Y)$ is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/covariancexsquaredybivariategeometricpmf.png))</sub>

where I am using the `Cov` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to help automate the calculation. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors.

Comment: Thanks, but can you refer me to the approach (method) been taken to come up with this result.

Comment: The same as doing it by hand, but automated. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I first try to calculate $E(X^2Y)=\sum_{i,j=0}^{\infty}i^2jP(X=i,Y=j)=\sum_{i,j=0}^{\infty}\binom{i+j-2}{i-1}i(i+j)(i+j-1)p^iq^j(1-p-q)$. Here I couldn't come up with anything useful. Now I am trying with Stein’s Lemma for discrete distribution, but I am not sure if this is correct.